# Получение значений из сокета

Tags: c#

Клиент записывает в сокет последовательно значения Uint, Uint, Short...
Получаю байты из сокета так

```
bytes = new byte[1024]; 
bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
```

Как из них можно считать в значения в порядке Uint, Uint, Short?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.toint32?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Нужно предусмотреть повторное дочтение, если прочтется меньше 10 байт. Сокет не гарантирует прочтение всего пакета за раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
{
    uint value1 = reader.ReadUInt32();
    uint value2 = reader.ReadUInt32();
}
```

Comment: объявить ее до блока?

Comment: Уже объявлял, а потом в блоке присваивал, но тогда значение 0

Comment: А что будет если придут 6 байт вместо 10-ти? Вам советовали сначала сделать проверку на минимально допустимый размер буфера приёма, а уж потом обработку буфера.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 2

```
var v1 = System.BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes,0); // 32 = 4 байта
var v2 = System.BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes,4); // 32 = 4 байта
var v3 = System.BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes,8); // 4+4 = 8
```